# Get children type from union React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm searching for a way to retrieve the **type of my children's prop**. I've created a component that can receive as children a **single react element** or an **array of React elements** with specific props. According to the type of my children, I need to perform different actions. How can I understand the type of my children?

```
const CodeFragmentsWrapper: React.FC<{ children?: React.ReactElement<MyProps> | React.ReactElement<MyProps>[] }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        children.isAnArray //HOW TO DO THIS? (or something similar)
        ? //DO SOMETHING
        : //DO SOMETHING ELSE
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `Array.isArray(children)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting React children array length in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738411/detecting-react-children-array-length-in-typescript)

Comment: add a check for undefined children https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIFcC2cTIN4CwAUMqciHJhAFzIDOYUoA5gNzFnJzM3lYBG0dkQC+xYjHQgEYYAHtcAdwAWcgBTKsOOgH5aGbLgA+aLSADaAXQCU+DmWAwNZutcIkyAQShQ4ATwA6YDpvXz9nQ1dke1IdZE1I8wAGSwCKKhjkWgTtNMoITLFRIA

Comment: Array.isArray works but it doesn't allow me to recognize the type of my props

Comment: You will never be able to get the props type for `JSX` children.  The `ReactElement` type only gets the generic set when called with `React.createElement`.  It is much easier if your children are functions or components instead of elements.

Comment: These answers might help you: [Is there a way to extract the type of the props of a JSX Element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754751/10431574) and [TypeScript and JSX don't understand cases when I want to set specific props](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64180136/10431574)